# Faction Transfer to Alliance; Worgen issues?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If I use the scroll of resurrection to boost a Horde character to level 80, then use the free transfer server and faction transfer to my friend's alliance server, if I choose to become a Worgen will I then have to do their starting area before I can venture into the world? The scroll FAQ says you are in the capital city, but phasing might make things problematic!

Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: I believe 'capital city' refers to Stormwind in all cases. It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure that I woke up in Orgrimar when I went the other way, and I've never played an Orc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you log into World of Warcraft after faction changing a character, you will always start in that faction's home city.

The exception to this is if you faction change an established character to the Worgen or Goblin race, as their 'home' cities are phased starting areas for new characters. In these instances you will end up in their 'associated' home city (the cities where the faction quartermaster resides), IE: Darnassus for Worgen, and Orgrimmar for Goblins.

The exception to the rule is if you change races within a faction - IE: Undead to Orc, in which case your hearthstone will remain at it's previous location.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure that when I faction changed to Tauren I was ported to Orgrimmar.

Comment: The only way that will happen is if you went from one Horde race to another - the location of your hearthstone is only reset if you change *faction* - where faction is "Horde" or "Alliance". For example, I recently changed faction and race from Alliance/Draenei to Horde/Blood Elf, and started in Silvermoon City when I logged in...

Comment: @Pixel Does this mean I won't be able to see the phased starting area quests; I'll have effectively already completed them?

Comment: @Nick honestly, I'm not sure - I've never actually gone back to try them. You definitely can't get back to Kezan (the Goblin starter area) but I am unsure about the Worgan starting area - I would suspect not though as the storyline for Gilneas has you started as a human that has not yet been afflicted with the curse...

Comment: @Nick No, you [can't get back to Gilneas once you leave](http://www.wowwiki.com/Gilneas_City). Attempting to enter Gilneas after you have left the starter area will result in you entering a completely abandoned Gilneas.